# What is distortion of a channel in an image?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I am relatively new to image processing, and I have a basic question: **what is a distortion of red/green/blue channel, and the distortion of the entire image ?**
taken from the imagemagick home site, in the [`compare` command section](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/compare.php):

> In addition to the visual interpretation of the difference in an image and its reconstruction, we report a mathematical measure of the difference:
>
> magick compare -verbose -metric mae rose.jpg reconstruct.jpg
>   difference.png Image: rose.jpg  Channel distortion: MAE   red: 2282.91
>   (0.034835)   green: 1853.99 (0.0282901)   blue: 2008.67 (0.0306503)
>   all: 1536.39 (0.0234439)

I dont understand the concept, can someone explain it to me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's nothing to do with shape transformation or `-distort` if that is what is confusing you. All that *"distortion"* means, in this context, is *"the specific error metric you requested"*. When comparing images there are various *"metrics"* you can select to measure:

- AE
- MAE
- DSSIM
- RMSE
- etc.

and so on. The *"distortion"* is just a generic term meaning *"whichever one of those you selected"*.

Here is a little example, a 100x10 red rectangle on a large black background.

```
convert -size 100x10 xc:red -bordercolor black -border 100 a.png
```

[image]

Now roll that 1-pixel to the right and re-save as `b.png`:

```
convert a.png -roll +1+0 b.png
```

[image]

Now compare absolute error:

```
compare -metric ae [ab].png null:
20
```

and you can see that the 10 pixels on the left and 10 pixels on the right of the red bar are "distorted".

Now roll down one pixel instead of across and compare again:

```
convert a.png -roll +0+1 b.png
compare -metric ae [ab].png null:
200
```

and the *"distortion"* is 100 pixels along the top pf the red bar that have become black and 100 pixels below the bottom of the red bar that have become red.

---

It may make more sense if you use the `convert` based method of comparing rather than the `compare` method. Here, you use the more common `convert` command with 2 images and then use `-compare` as the operator but you now will see the *variable* called **distortion** being used and that it just refers to whatever `-metric` you selected:

```
convert a.png b.png -metric AE -compare -format "%[distortion]" info:
200
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Mark. Although I will accept it, I asked the same question at the Imagemagick forums and the simple answer was, in short, "distortion = difference". A combination of that along with your great image examples would have been the perfect answer.